# HttpContext can't be referenced in supporting method call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I need to make use of two steps in multiple places on my .NET Core website. I've decided to implement an interface and supporting class in my `Startup.cs` so I can use DI to inject the object into my `PageModel` on various Razor pages in my project.

### Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticatedGraphClient, AuthenticatedGraphClient>();
```

### Interface:

```
public interface IAuthenticatedGraphClient
{
    Task<GraphServiceClient> GetAuthenticatedGraphClientAsync(HttpContext httpContext);
}
```

### Implementing Class:

```
public class AuthenticatedGraphClient : IAuthenticatedGraphClient
{
    private ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition;

    public AuthenticatedGraphClient(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
    {
        this.tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    }

    public async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetAuthenticatedGraphClientAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var accessToken = await TokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser(httpContext, new[] { ScopeConstants.ScopeUserRead });

        return new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => {
            requestMessage
                .Headers
                .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }));
    }
}
```

### PageModel:

```
public class TestPageModel : PageModel
{
    private IAuthenticatedGraphClient graphClient;

    public TestPage(IAuthenticatedGraphClient graphClient)
    {
        this.graphClient = graphClient;
    }

    public async Task OnPostAsync()
    {
        var graphServiceClient = await graphClient.GetAuthenticatedGraphClientAsync(HttpContext);
        //truncated for brevity...
    }
}
```

I thought I had to provide the `HttpContext` from the `PageModel` class into the called method but I'm not entirely sure as this gives me an error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser(HttpContext, IEnumerable, string)'

I've also tried:

```
var accessToken = await TokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser(HttpContext, new[] { ScopeConstants.ScopeUserRead });
```

...however this gives me the error:

> 'HttpContext' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

If I put the `GetAuthenticatedGraphClientAsync` as a method in the same `PageModel` class it works without issue and `HttpContext` is understood.

Any ideas? Is there a better pattern?

Comment: Razor pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error about an object reference being required, would seem to be because your `AuthenticatedGraphClient` constructor takes an `ITokenAcquisition` parameter, which you don't seem to be passing in your `Startup.cs`

As for your second error about `HttpContext` being a type, that is true, I'm pretty sure you should be passing `HttpContext.Current` into `GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser`.

EDIT: Also, you're not even using the passed in `ITokenAcquisition`.

`var accessToken = await TokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser(httpContext, new[] { ScopeConstants.ScopeUserRead });`

should be:

`var accessToken = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser(httpContext, new[] { ScopeConstants.ScopeUserRead });`

Comment: yes, not sure how I forgot that. i wrote out the example by hand and typed a capital T; I changed `TokenAcquisition` to the field `tokenAcquisition` and the error is gone. Also, there was no need to specify `.Current` in HttpContext. I'm getting a different error now about the Graph client; i'll post another q.